# Making an object available in Shiny outside renderPlot for renderTable

Tags: r, object, scope, shiny, scoping

I'm drafting a simple Shiny App that provides access to a dynamic chart and a corresponding table. The relevant part of the `server.R` code looks like that:

```
output$some_plot<- renderPlot({
    # Subset data on change in the indicator selection
    chrt_demo_dta <- subset(x = dta_la_demo, 
                            subset = <<my-conditions>>>)
    # Define the demography chart
    ggplot(data = chrt_demo_dta, aes(x = variable_a, y = variable_b)) +
      geom_line(aes(colour = GEOGRAPHY_NAME), size = 2) +
      theme_bw()}, height = 650, width = 800)

  # Section generating table
  output$chrt_demo_dta_tbl <- renderTable({chrt_demo_dta})
```

The problem occurs when I try to access the table I get the following error message:

> Error in func() : object 'chrt_demo_dta' not found

It appears that the object `chrt_demo_dta` is created outside the scoping rules of the `renderTable`. My question is how can I achieve the following:

1. I want for the chart and the corresponding table to update dynamically upon the selection, hence my idea to embed the `subset` command in the `renderPlot` which works
2. I want to make use of the same subset in a corresponding table. Ideally, I would like to **avoid repeating** the subset command. As I have the required data frame ready it appears that it is only a matter of accessing it via the `renderTable`

---

*I'm aware the the code is not fully reproducible but at this stage I'm not necessarily looking for a particular solution but a more generic guidance whether it would be possible to access an object created within one server element from other server element.* If the push comes to shove, I could encapsule the subsetting mechanism in a function and call it twice but it seems to be rather messy solution.

Comment: You should make chrt_demo_dta reactive, e.g., have `chrt_demo_dta <- reactive({subset(dta_la_demo...})` in your server body and then reference it in `renderPlot` and `renderTable` with `chrt_demo_dta()`

Comment: What about making `chrt_demo_dta` a global variable, using the double arrow <<-, that way you can access it within any function outside the renderPlot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <<- operator may have unwanted consequences. It sends results to the shared environment, where it is visible to all users of the session. Not only will this create a race-condition where they try to over-write each other, it may expose confidential work to others. You have two solutions: 1) repeat the steps in each local environment, 2) write the result to disk with a unique name (e.g. Sys.time() + data hash). Then you can retrieve it when needed elsewhere. Don't forget to delete the saved file though, or your storage will be consumed.

Comment: IMO, the solution suggested by @Matthew Plourde in the comment above is the way to go, not writing to disk.

Answer (score 1):

In the `server` function of `server.R`:

```
# Create reactive object w/in server func
chrt_demo_dta <- reactiveVal()

output$some_plot<- renderPlot({
  chrt_demo_dta.temp <- subset(
    x = dta_la_demo, 
      subset = <<my-conditions>>>)
  # Update the obj within scope of nested function
  chrt_demo_dta(chrt_demo_dta.temp)
})

# Access of the updated obj is now possible in original scope
output$chrt_demo_dta_tbl <- renderTable({chrt_demo_dta()})
```

See related: [Shiny : How to modify reactive object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285090/shiny-how-to-modify-reactive-object)