# How to change a value in a reactive tibble in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I would like to update the content of a reactive object that is holding a tibble in response to a button push and I can't figure out the syntax.  The solution that was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285090/shiny-how-to-modify-reactive-object) contains a solution that used to work but now it throws an error.

Below is a reprex of the issue I am having.  Run the `write.csv(iris, "text.csv")` first.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# create the test data first
# write.csv(iris, "text.csv")

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    in_data <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$raw
        x <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE)
    })

    subset <- reactive({
        subset <- in_data() %>%
            filter(Species == "setosa")
    })

    observeEvent(input$pushme, {
            subset()$Sepal.Length[2] <- 2
    })

    output$theOutput <- renderTable({
        subset()
    })
})


ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        fileInput('raw', 'Load test.csv'),
        actionButton("pushme","Push Me"),
        tableOutput('theOutput')     
    )
)
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

My code to change the value:

```
subset()$Sepal.Length[2] <- 2
```

Throws this error:

```
Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

What is the syntax for programmatically changing the value in a reactive tibble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify directly the value of a reactive object. You have to define first a static object that will take the value of the reactive object, and then you can modify the value of the static object. Two options for you (no modifications in `ui`):

- The first one is to use `renderTable` just after having subseted your data, and then to modify your table inside `observeEvent`:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  in_data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$raw
    x <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE)
  })

  test1 <- reactive({
    data <- in_data() %>%
      filter(Species == "setosa")
    data
  })

  output$theOutput <- renderTable({
    req(input$raw)
    test1()
  })

  observeEvent(input$pushme, {
    output$theOutput <- renderTable({
      req(input$raw)
      test1 <- test1()
      test1$Sepal.Length[2] <- 2
      test1
    })
  })

})
```

- The second one is to define another dataset (`test2` here) that will be computed with `eventReactive` only if the button is pushed. Then you have to define which of the two datasets you want to use in `renderTable` using conditions on their existence:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  in_data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$raw
    x <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE)
  })

  test1 <- reactive({
    data <- in_data() %>%
      filter(Species == "setosa")
    data
  })

  test2 <- eventReactive(input$pushme, {
      test1 <- test1()
      test1$Sepal.Length[2] <- 2
      test1
    }
  )

  output$theOutput <- renderTable({
    if (input$pushme) {
      test2()
    }
    else {
      req(input$raw)
      test1()
    }
  })

})
```

By the way, you shouldn't call datasets (reactive or not) like function names. In your example, you have called `subset` the reactive dataset you modify. This is not good since this dataset will be used as `subset()` (because it is reactive). It may be confusing both for you and for the execution of the code.